# Problema con consulta SQL en el 'OR'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy tratando de ejecutar un SP, pero me arroja el siguiente error `Línea 23
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0R2' to data type int.`

Realizando una prueba de escritorio, el sp logra ejecutarse hasta el `where`, pero cuando ejecuto el sp con los `OR`me arroja el error, no encuentro cual sería el problema de los `OR`.

Comparto el código:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PRC_DOC_BuscarDocumento] 
-- PARAMETROS
@COLUMNA VARCHAR(50), 
@FILTRO  VARCHAR(150)
AS
    BEGIN
        --SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(t.CDOC, 3), DATEPART(YEAR, FECH), '-', SUBSTRING(t.CDOC, 4, 10)) AS RADICADO, 
               t.FECH FECHA, 
               tu.NUSU RADICA, 
               CASE
               WHEN t.CEMP = 1
               THEN 'EMPRESA 1'
               WHEN t.CEMP = 2
               THEN 'EMPRESA 2'
               ELSE 'EMPRESA 3'
               END AS EMPRESA, 
               t.DOCU DOCUMENTO, 
               t.SOPO SOPORTE, 
               tp.NPROV PROVEEDOR, 
               t.FACT FACTURA, 
               td.NDES DESTINATARIO, 
               t.DESOPC DES_OPCIONAL, 
               t.OBS OBSERVACIONES, 
               t.ESTA, 
               t.FDOC FDOCUMENTAL, 
               t1.NUSU USUARIOD, 
               t.ESTB, 
               t2.NUSU USUARIOC, 
               t.FCON FCONTABILIDAD, 
               t.ESTC, 
               t.FECHP RECIBIDA,
               CASE
                   WHEN t.EPROV = '1'
                   THEN 'SI'
                   ELSE 'NO'
               END AS EN_PROVEEDOR, 
               t.ESTD, 
               t.FENVI ENVIADA,
               CASE
                   WHEN t.ANULADA = '1'
                   THEN 'SI'
                   ELSE 'NO'
               END AS ANULADA
        FROM TDOCUMENTAL t
             INNER JOIN TUSUARIOS tu ON t.CUSU = tu.CUSU
             LEFT JOIN TUSUARIOS t1 ON t.USUD = t1.CUSU
             LEFT JOIN TUSUARIOS t2 ON t.USUC = t2.CUSU
             --INNER JOIN TEMPRESAS te ON t.CEMP = te.CEMP
             INNER JOIN TPROVEEDORES_AG_TEMP tp ON t.CPROV = tp.CPROV
             INNER JOIN TDESTINATARIOS td ON t.CDES = td.CDES
        WHERE t.DOCU <> 'NO RADICABLE'
              OR (@COLUMNA = 'FACTURA'
                  AND t.FACT LIKE '%' + @FILTRO + '%')
              OR (@COLUMNA = 'PROVEEDOR'
                  AND tp.NPROV LIKE '%' + @FILTRO + '%')
              OR (@COLUMNA = 'NIT'
                  AND t.CPROV LIKE '%' + @FILTRO + '%')
              OR (@COLUMNA = 'RADICADO'
                  AND t.CDOC LIKE '%' + @FILTRO + '%')
              OR (@COLUMNA = 'DESTINATARIO'
                  AND td.NDES LIKE '%' + @FILTRO + '%')
        ORDER BY LEFT(t.CDOC, 3), 
                 CAST(REPLACE(t.CDOC, LEFT(t.CDOC, 3), 0) AS INT) ASC;
    END;
```

Agradezco sus aportes!

Comment: Probablemente una de esas columnas que estan en el LIKE no sea un varchar, y por eso tira el error. No es que va a revisar y usar solo la parte que vos queres, trata de reemplazar la variable en todas las partes, y luego revisa los tipos y por eso tira el error. Creo que deberias probar un select dinamico.

Comment: @gbianchi, Gracias por responder, no creo que sea por los tipos de columnas ya que todas las que estan referenciadas en el LIKE son de tipo varchar, me puedes regalar una orientación del select dinamico?

Comment: CRPOV es varchar? dudo que hayas puesto un codigo como varchar.

Comment: Es correcto CPROV  es varchar ya que es un código que puede estar conformado por caracteres alfanumericos, pero su clave principal es una columna int  la cual es IDPROV pero para el ejemplo del select no la necesito.

Comment: uno de todos esos campos es int. prueba ir metiendo el or de a uno...

Comment: O puedes simplemente ver la definición de las tablas TDOCUMENTAL y TDESTINATARIOS para conocer los tipos de datos de las columnas.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que uno (o más) de los campos utilizados en el WHERE es tipo int. Eso indica que al comparar un tipo de dato diferente, se tiene que hacer una conversión implicita al tipo con mayor precedencia. El tipo de dato `int` tiene mayor precedencia que el tipo `varchar` por lo que se busca convertir a `int`.
Para conocer rápidamente los tipos de las columnas, puedes hacer un query a la vista `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` así.

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
JOIN (VALUES(N'TDOCUMENTAL', N'FACT'),
            (N'TDOCUMENTAL', N'CPROV'),
            (N'TDOCUMENTAL', N'CDOC'),
            (N'TPROVEEDORES_AG_TEMP', N'NPROV'),
            (N'TDESTINATARIOS', N'NDES'))x(Tabla,Columa) ON c.TABLE_NAME = x.Tabla 
AND c.COLUMN_NAME = x.Columa;
```

Una vez hecho eso, deberás ajustar tu búsqueda. En este caso, a motivo de ejemplo, asumo que la columna NPROV es integer. Por lo tanto, no agrego los signos de porcentaje y cambio el LIKE por un signo de igual. También cambié tu consulta para hacerla óptima y no tener un plan mediocre por mantenerlo seguro.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PRC_DOC_BuscarDocumento] 
-- PARAMETROS
@COLUMNA VARCHAR(50), 
@FILTRO  VARCHAR(150)
AS
--SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
IF @COLUMNA = 'PROVEEDOR'
    SET @FILTRO = TRY_CONVERT( int, @FILTRO); --Esto previene que se incluyan valores que no se puedan convertir a enteros
ELSE
    SET @FILTRO =  '%' + @FILTRO + '%';

SET @SQL = N'
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(t.CDOC, 3), DATEPART(YEAR, FECH), ''-'', SUBSTRING(t.CDOC, 4, 10)) AS RADICADO, 
        t.FECH FECHA, 
        tu.NUSU RADICA, 
        CASE
        WHEN t.CEMP = 1
        THEN ''EMPRESA 1''
        WHEN t.CEMP = 2
        THEN ''EMPRESA 2''
        ELSE ''EMPRESA 3''
        END AS EMPRESA, 
        t.DOCU DOCUMENTO, 
        t.SOPO SOPORTE, 
        tp.NPROV PROVEEDOR, 
        t.FACT FACTURA, 
        td.NDES DESTINATARIO, 
        t.DESOPC DES_OPCIONAL, 
        t.OBS OBSERVACIONES, 
        t.ESTA, 
        t.FDOC FDOCUMENTAL, 
        t1.NUSU USUARIOD, 
        t.ESTB, 
        t2.NUSU USUARIOC, 
        t.FCON FCONTABILIDAD, 
        t.ESTC, 
        t.FECHP RECIBIDA,
        CASE
            WHEN t.EPROV = ''1''
            THEN ''SI''
            ELSE ''NO''
        END AS EN_PROVEEDOR, 
        t.ESTD, 
        t.FENVI ENVIADA,
        CASE
            WHEN t.ANULADA = ''1''
            THEN ''SI''
            ELSE ''NO''
        END AS ANULADA
FROM TDOCUMENTAL t
        INNER JOIN TUSUARIOS tu ON t.CUSU = tu.CUSU
        LEFT JOIN TUSUARIOS t1 ON t.USUD = t1.CUSU
        LEFT JOIN TUSUARIOS t2 ON t.USUC = t2.CUSU
        --INNER JOIN TEMPRESAS te ON t.CEMP = te.CEMP
        INNER JOIN TPROVEEDORES_AG_TEMP tp ON t.CPROV = tp.CPROV
        INNER JOIN TDESTINATARIOS td ON t.CDES = td.CDES
WHERE t.DOCU <> ''NO RADICABLE''' + NCHAR(10)
+ CASE  WHEN @COLUMNA = 'FACTURA'        THEN N' AND t.FACT LIKE @FILTRO ' + NCHAR(10)
        WHEN @COLUMNA = 'PROVEEDOR'      THEN N' AND tp.NPROV = @FILTRO ' + NCHAR(10)
        WHEN @COLUMNA = 'NIT'            THEN N' AND t.CPROV LIKE @FILTRO ' + NCHAR(10)
        WHEN @COLUMNA = 'RADICADO'       THEN N' AND t.CDOC LIKE @FILTRO ' + NCHAR(10)
        WHEN @COLUMNA = 'DESTINATARIO'   THEN N' AND td.NDES LIKE @FILTRO ' + NCHAR(10)
        ELSE '' END + NCHAR(10) 
+ N'ORDER BY LEFT(t.CDOC, 3), 
            CAST(REPLACE(t.CDOC, LEFT(t.CDOC, 3), 0) AS INT) ASC;';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@FILTRO  VARCHAR(150)', @FILTRO = @FILTRO;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, te pregunto el campo NPROV es un varchar, con el ejemplo que me compartes quitando el (=) y cambiandolo por un (Like) solo me trae el nombre si lo copio tal cual esta, como puedo agregar los (%%) en las consultas dinamicas?

Comment: Por eso está la validación al inicio. Una de tus columnas en int y por eso ocurre el error. Si ninguna de las 5 columnas que se comparan con el filtro son integer, es probable que una de las otras columnas involucradas en alguna comparación lo sean. O tal vez `t.CEMP` sea varchar y tenga valores que no puedan ser convertidos a enteros.

Comment: Creo que no me explique bien, con tu ejemplo funciona bien la consulta, ya no tengo el problema de la conversión, la duda que se me genera es que "NPROV" al ser un campo varchar, como puedo agregarle los conectores (%%) para que la consulta me devuleva datos segun coincidan los valores en el LIKE de NPROV

Comment: Es porque mi código asume que NPROV es integer. Si es varchar, puedes quitar el código del `IF @COLUMNA = 'PROVEEDOR'` y dejar sólo `SET @FILTRO =  '%' + @FILTRO + '%';` además de cambiar el = por LIKE.